# Check if the undirected graph is cyclic

Tags: java, interview-questions, graph

Here is my approach. Do DFS and check in stack whether the new node is already in the Stack or not.

```
public static boolean isCyclicDFS(int[][] adjMat) {
        int len = adjMat.length;
        boolean[] isVisited = new boolean[len];
        for(int i =0; i<len; i++) {
            isVisited[i] = false;
        }

        Stack s = new Stack<>();
        s.add(0);

        while(!s.isEmpty()) {
            int current = (int) s.pop();
            System.out.println(current);
            isVisited[current] = true;
            for(int i =0; i<len; i++) {
                if(adjMat[current][i] ==1 && isVisited[i] == false) {
                    if(s.contains(i)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    s.push(i);
                    break;
                }
            }



        }
        return true;

    }
```

Kindly suggest if any improvement/correction.

Answer (score 5):

### Formatting

Your spacing is inconsistent, which makes the code harder to read. By the original conventions released with the language, `=`, `==`, and `<` should have a whitespace character on either side. Whatever you choose, make it consistent.

### Implementation

Your `System.out.println` is for debugging and should be removed.

Use `Arrays.fill()` to populate your array.

Declaring `len` makes the code harder to read. Just refer to the length in your `for` loop.

As @Marc-Andre said, prefer a `Deque` to a `Stack`. And use generics.

Don't do `if (foo == false)`. Use `if (!foo)`.

I'm in the minority, but I prefer explicit boxing rather than autoboxing for clarity.

Don't use abbreviations for variable names. The extra characters enhance readability and cost nothing.

If it's in your control, for a non-weighted graph the adjacency matrix should probably be a `boolean[][]`, not an `int[][]`. If this is a weighted graph, checking if the value `== 1` is almost certainly a bug.

### Correctness

You detect a cycle in this graph: `{ { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 } }`. Is it really a cycle if any two nodes are adjacent to each other? Is this an unweighted directed graph?

You also detect a cycle in this graph: `{ { 0, 1 }, { 0, 0 } }`. Surely that is not correct. Please test before posting. CodeReview is for reviewing working code, not fixing broken code.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     boolean[] isVisited = new boolean[len];
>     for(int i =0; i<len; i++) {
>         isVisited[i] = false;
>     }
> ```

This could easily be inside another method, something like `initializeIsVisited()` that return a `boolean[]`.

The format of your code is slightly inconsistent or not ideal to read. Like `for(int i =0; i<len; i++) {` should probably look like `for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {`. I've added some space, this helps separate each thing in the expression. You should probably used the format option of your IDE or look at a standard.

If I'm not mistaken, `Stack` is kind of not used anymore. If you read the `Stack` javadoc you will see that they suggest to use `Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();`. The contract from the interface respect the contract of a real Stack. `Stack` provides more methods that you need to represent a LIFO.

You should not used raw collections, this will remove those unnecessary cast `int current = (int) s.pop();`